# My program doesn't recognize header files

Tags: c++11, include

So what I'm trying to do is to get this "menu.cpp" recognize "menu.h", but it doesn't

[This is menu.h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHlJ3.png)

[This is the error I get on menu.cpp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKkkd.png)

Comment: Instead of posting pictures, can you put the relevant code in the actual body of the question?

Comment: Make sure you have included `menu.cpp` & `menu.h` file in `HW.pro` file. Otherwise they won't be a part of the build. Also, as mchen.ja mentions try posting the real code instead of image captures.